# How SessionTimeout extend on redis

Tags: session, redis, session-cookies, session-state, session-timeout

I am using redis session on a project, and for some reason user can not logoff.
My configuration is as follows:

```
<sessionState timeout="3" mode="Custom" customProvider="MySession">
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="7" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

I set `SessionTimeout` to 3 min (180sec) and `FormAuthentication timeout=7`. Actually I have a `SessionExpireAttribute` but I canceled it because I want to know the problem where is it coming from. So I was watching session on redis using redis desktop manager, after 3 min session killed by redis, then I waited to expire form authentication (7min) after that i have clicked a button on page, I thought I should be logged out but it wasn't because session has been created again by redis and I have checked `SessionTimeout` I have seen 3600 sec (60 min). I don't understand what happened!!.